# Count duplicate (but unique records) + consecutive records

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to count the number of invoices that are consecutive + duplicate dates (but unique invoices). I tried converting datetime to string then counting sequences but it only counts unique dates per invoice.

```
# fix time format
df['Invoice Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'])

# column to find sequences
df = df.sort_values(['Vendor ID', 'Vendor Name', 'Invoice Date'])
df['continue'] = df['Invoice Date'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()

# find time sequences
val_count = df['continue'].value_counts()
val_count = val_count[val_count.gt(1)].index.tolist()


#filter and group by Vendor
output = df[df['continue'].isin(val_count)].groupby(['Vendor ID'])['Vendor Name'].count()
```

Current Input:

| Vendor ID | Vendor Name | Invoice Date | Invoice Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8555 | Macys | 1/1/2020 | 1 |
| 8555 | Macys | 1/2/2020 | 2 |
| 8555 | Macys | 1/3/2020 | 3 |
| 8555 | Macys | 1/3/2020 | 4 |
| 8555 | Macys | 1/3/2020 | 5 |
| 8555 | Macys | 1/5/2020 | 6 |
| 1044 | JC Penny | 2/2/2020 | 7 |
| 1044 | JC Penny | 2/3/2020 | 8 |
| 1044 | JC Penny | 2/3/2020 | 9 |
| 1044 | JC Penny | 2/8/2020 | 10 |
| 1044 | JC Penny | 2/8/2020 | 11 |

Expected Output:

| Vendor ID | Vendor Name | Count of Consecutive Invoices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8555 | Macys | 5 |
| 1044 | JC Penny | 5 |

**August 24:******I'M EDITING MY INPUT AND EXPECTED OUTPUT. The code everyone's suggesting was working on the previous example I gave but not on my actual data. Adding onto it so it reflects what I'm running into. I've used all code suggestions and nothing is giving Macys 5, JC Penny 5.****

- Macys has a sum of 5. Invoices 1-5 are consecutive and contain duplicates.
- JC Penny has a sum of 5. Invoices 7-11 are include consecutive of 2 days and contains duplicates.

**August 25:******Adding a new example with current code (with the help of @Corralien) and dataframe****

```
d = {'Vendor ID':
         {0: 8555, 1: 8555, 2: 8555, 3: 8555, 4: 8555, 5: 8555, 6: 8555,7: 8555, 8: 8555,9: 8555, 10: 8555, 11: 8555, 12: 8555, 13: 8555,
                   14: 1044, 15: 1044, 16: 1044, 17: 1044, 18: 1044, 19: 1044, 20: 1044, 21: 1044},
 'Vendor Name':
         {0: 'Macys', 1: 'Macys', 2: 'Macys', 3: 'Macys', 4: 'Macys',5: 'Macys', 6: 'Macys', 7: 'Macys', 8: 'Macys', 9: 'Macys', 10: 'Macys', 11: 'Macys', 12: 'Macys', 13: 'Macys',
                  14: 'JC Penny', 15: 'JC Penny', 16: 'JC Penny', 17: 'JC Penny', 18: 'JC Penny', 19: 'JC Penny', 20: 'JC Penny',21: 'JC Penny'},
 'Invoice Date':
         {0: '7/31/2020', 1: '7/31/2020', 2: '7/31/2020', 3: '7/31/2020', 4: '7/31/2020', 5: '2/14/2020', 6: '12/31/2019',7: '12/23/2019', 8: '7/14/2020', 9: '6/30/2020' , 10: '6/30/2020',
                  11: '6/30/2020',  12: '6/30/2020', 13: '6/30/2020', 14: '3/30/2020', 15: '3/20/2020', 16: '3/20/2020', 17: '3/20/2020', 18: '3/20/2020', 19: '2/27/2020', 20: '2/26/2020', 21: '2/26/2020'},
 'Invoice Number':
         {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# fix time format
df['Invoice Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'])

def count_consecutive_invoice(sr):
    # Find days that are less than or equal to 1 day (m1)
    m1 = sr.diff().le(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
    #  find first days of consecutive days (which is False in m1)
    m2 = (m1.eq(False) & m1.shift(-1).eq(True))
    return m1.sum() + m2.sum()

output = df.groupby(['Vendor ID', 'Vendor Name'])['Invoice Date'] \
      .apply(count_consecutive_invoice) \
      .rename('Count of Consecutive Invoices') \
      .reset_index()
```

Current Output:

```
   Vendor ID Vendor Name  Count of Consecutive Invoices
0       1044    JC Penny                              8
1       8555       Macys                             14
```

Expected Output

```
   Vendor ID Vendor Name  Count of Consecutive Invoices
0       1044    JC Penny                              7
1       8555       Macys                             10
```

Comment: For an invoice (`Vender ID`), if you have 4 consecutive dates then a break of 2 days and again 3 consecutive dates, the count should be 4 (the longest) or 7 (the sum)?

Comment: I edited your question to normalize "JCPenny" to "JC Penny" as doing a simple replace on the "Vendor Name" to normalize text wasn't really part of your question.

Comment: @Corralien The unique invoice would be Invoice Number (1-8). it would be the sum of consecutive dates. So 7. Thanks!!

Comment: Edited your column label in sample input / output from `Vender ID` to `Vendor ID` to be consistent with your codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each group:

- `m1`: find days are less than or equal to 1 day (m1)
- `m2`: find first days of consecutive days (which is False in m1)

Then sum the 2 series.

```
def count_consecutive_invoice(sr):
    m1 = sr.sort_values().diff().le(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
    m2 = (m1.eq(False) & m1.shift(-1).eq(True))
    return m1.sum() + m2.sum()
```

```
# Ensure your 'Invoice Date' column is datetime64
# df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

>>> df.groupby(['Vendor ID', 'Vendor Name'])['Invoice Date'] \
      .apply(count_consecutive_invoice) \
      .rename('Count of Consecutive Invoices') \
      .reset_index()

   Vendor ID Vendor Name  Count of Consecutive Invoices
0       1044    JC Penny                              5
1       8555       Macys                              5
```

On your real data, the output is now:

```
   Vendor ID Vendor Name  Count of Consecutive Invoices
0       1044    JC Penny                              7
1       8555       Macys                             10
```

Comment: This works on the example I gave you but not on my actual data :( it seems to be counting all rows .. I'll keep working on it with your logic

Comment: I updated my current input and desired output. With this code, I'm getting 4 for JC Penny and 5 for Macys. The new expected outcome is above. This came closer than anyones...

Comment: @Meowzz. I updated my answer with your new data. Can you check that is work for your real data, please?

Comment: Appreciate the tips! I didn't know that.. Will go back and update my other posts. As far as the code, it seems to work on the new example I gave so thank you for that. Its not counting correctly on my actual data which is almost identical to the example.  Can you tell me what "le" means. I get sr.diff() and (pd.Timedelta(days=1)) is finding the difference in dates less than or equal to 1 day.

Comment: [`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) means 'less than or equal to'. Can you tell me what's wrong with your real data?

Comment: Interesting...ok. I thought le would've been the issue but its what I need. I updated my original post with the real data (Aug 25 update). I used your code on this new data set and am getting different results than expected.

Comment: In your previous sample, all dates are already sorted but it's not the case. Just sort values either in the function or before the groupby. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `groupby` two times, unless you want to do an un uglier (and perhaps less performant) `groupby` with `lambda x` row by row. The main issue is that you didn't use `groupby` with `diff`.

```
df['Count of Consecutive Invoices'] = df.groupby('Vendor ID')['Invoice Date'].diff().dt.days.le(1)
df.groupby(['Vendor ID', 'Vendor Name'], sort=False)['Count of Consecutive Invoices'].sum().add(1).reset_index()
Out[1]: 
   Vendor ID Vendor Name  Count of Consecutive Invoices
0       1044    JC Penny                              4
1       8555       Macys                              3
```

Comment: I edited my input and expected output with data that's more similar to mine. Although your code worked for the previous example, it was not working on my actual data. I tried your code on my new example and its incorrect.. :( I'm now expecting sum of 5 for both Macys and JC Penny. –

Answer (score 0):

See whether this is what you want:

Similar to your codes, the codes below counts upto the distinct `Invoice Date` within a group of [`Vendor ID` `Vendor Name`]:

```
(df.groupby(['Vendor ID', 'Vendor Name'], as_index=False)['Invoice Date']
   .nunique()
   .rename({'Invoice Date': 'Count of Consecutive Invoices'}, axis=1)
)
```

**Result:**

```
   Vendor ID Vendor Name  Count of Consecutive Invoices
0       1044    JC Penny                              4
1       8555       Macys                              3
```

Comment: If you have a vendor with invoice dates of 1/1/2021, 1/3/2021, 1/5/2021, then your answer with `nunique()` would output `3`, but I think the answer is supposed to be `1`, since there is only one consecutive day. I think the OP is interested in number of consecutive days, not number of distinct values per group.